# Can an AS3539 Sensor be made to "just" report distance to lightning strikes?

Tags: sensors

I recently added an AS3539 Lightning Sensor to my IoT network, but found out that the sensor reports distance to the closest lightning strike over the last 10 minutes or so, no matter how far away a strike might be right now.  This is to denote the "edge of the storm", rather than the real distance to the strike.

Does anyone know of a way to make it *just* report lightning strike distance, versus the closest strike over the last 10 minutes??  Once the storm is within 1 km, it never waivers from that reading, even though the storm could now be 30 miles away.  It only seems to reset if it detects no strikes for something like 30 minutes.

Comment: I don't think this is a good place to ask this question. It is specific to a single design of equipment made for a specialised field. Even though there are IoT applications of meteorology, I don't think you're asking about that here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a Clear History bit that needs to be toggled to allow the next strike to report its distance. Clear the AS3935 History after each strike (after obtaining the current data/distance info).